# Live search in laravel using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want users to be able to search and display results on any page.

Search box is in navbar like this:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result'); placeholder="Search"></div>
        <div id="result">
            @include('results')
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JQuery/AJAX:

```
function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/searching/' + search_value,
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#results').html(response); // put the returning html in the 'results' div
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function search() {
    $search_text = $_GET['text'];
    if ($search_text==NULL) {
        $data= Business::all();
    } else {
        $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
    }
    return view('results')->with('results',$data);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/searching', 'SearchController@search');
```

Results.blade.php

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach( $results as $business )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $business->logo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $business->name}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

This is what I have got so far and I am getting this error:

> Undefined variable: results
>  
>   (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\results.blade.php)
>   (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\results.blade.php)
>   (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\results.blade.php)

Can anyone kindly please help a poor soul?

Answer (score 1):

You are including the results view in the form blade, where the `results` variable in the results view is not initially available. You could instead do a check in the results view to make sure to loop through the collection only if the data is available

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
    </tr>
    @if (isset($results) && count($results) > 0)
    @foreach( $results as $business )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $business->logo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $business->name}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</table>
```

**EDIT**

You are using Route type `post` and ajax method as `get`. You need to change your ajax method

```
function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/searching/' + search_value,
        method: 'POST'
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#results').html(response); // put the returning html in the 'results' div
    });
}
```

and access that search text in your Controller as

```
public function search($search = null) {
    $search_text = $search;
    if ($search_text==NULL) {
        $data= Business::all();
    } else {
        $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
    }
    return view('results')->with('results',$data);
}
```

Comment: Apparently here: <div id="result"> there is : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: it points me to that div results actually, js seems to be fine

Comment: Your form and results.blade.php seems to be normal and without any bug, is there any other code in the results.blade.php

Comment: missing " after onkeyup that's what was causing it -.- i am getting no found http, so my route needs a variable, is it just a random one?

Comment: You aren't sending the csrf token with the ajax request, also you could use the helper method like `url` to generate the url

Comment: what you mean? i have added a header        headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
    } but i sitll have problem with route not being found /searching/anyinput

Comment: Can you do a `php artisan route:list --path=searching` and check if you could find a matching route `/searching/{parameter}` Could you post the route list results

Comment: λ --+ |        | POST   | searching/{search} |      | App\Http\Controllers\SearchController@search | web,auth

Comment: I still get token mismatch now, even after adding meta with token and adding header to ajax

Comment: Is this problem solved? I also had a problem using ajax search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how **->with()** works, but you can add data to your view helper directly with either of the two options:

```
return view('results', ['results' => $data]);
```

Or

```
return view('results', compact('data'));
```

Note that the last option will create a variable $data with the value of $data in your view.

Comment: it still says that results is not defined, thing is results is supposed to come back after there is an input in the search box otherwise of course it is empty and therefore not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_text" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result'); placeholder="Search"></div>
    <div id="result">
        @include('results')
    </div>
</div>
```

Route

```
 Route::get('/searching', 'SearchController@search');
```

controller

```
public function search() {
$search_text = $_GET['search_text'];
if ($search_text==NULL) {
    $data= Business::all();
} else {
    $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
}
return view('results')->with('results',$data);}
```

Results.blade.php

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Logo</th>
</tr>
@if (isset($results) && count($results) > 0)
@foreach( $results as $business )
<tr>
    <td>{{ $business->logo }}</td>
    <td>{{ $business->name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```